# Dijkstra's runtime analysis in terms of $|V|$ and $|E|$

Tags: runtime-analysis, dijkstras-algorithm

I'm unsure as to the amount of operations in Dijkstra's shortest path in terms of $|V|$ and $|E|$.

My guess is that there are (worst case - complete graph):

$$|V| + \sum^{|V|}_{i=1}{(|V|-i)} = \frac{|V| \cdot (|V| + 1)}{2} \implies O(|V|^2)$$

operations for a graph $G = (V, E)$, assuming there are no negative cycles.

---

Following the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) of Djikstra's, I interpreted:

1.

```
dist[source] ← 0

create vertex priority Q

for each vertex v in Graph.Vertices:          
    if v ≠ source
        dist[v] ← INFINITY               
        prev[v] ← UNDEFINED
    Q.add_with_priority(v, dist[v])
```

To be $|V|$ operations, from the iteration over each vertex. And for `Q` to be a length of $|V|$.

2.

Then for

```
while Q is not empty:                      
    u ← Q.extract_min()                   
    for each neighbor v of u:  // only v that are still in Q            
        alt ← dist[u] + Graph.Edges(u, v)
        if alt < dist[v] and dist[u] is not INFINITY:
            dist[v] ← alt
            prev[v] ← u
            Q.decrease_priority(v, alt)
```

to run the `while` loop exactly $|V|$ times (as you take one item from `Q` per iteration), which gives $|V| + |V| \cdot (\text{Inside of while loop operations})$ so far.

Then I thought that the `for` loop, in the `while` loop would be running $\sum^{|V|}_{i=1}{(|V|-i)}$ times total. As you are checking for each `v` still in `Q`, and you are removing one item from `Q` per loop (hence the $(|V|-i)$). Which then simplifies the total operations to my proposed answer.

---

Is this correct?

$$|V| + \sum^{|V|}_{i=1}{(|V|-i)} = \frac{|V| \cdot (|V| + 1)}{2} \implies O(|V|^2)$$

*I am only learning this stuff. I am not adept with CS*. Any constructive comments and tips would be appreciated

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you checked a textbook that covers Dijkstra's algorthm?  Any good one should summarize its time complexity.  Or, you could check Wikipedia, which also discusses its running time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time

Comment: @D.W., Just read that now. I now see that my summation was incorrect